# Disable the resizable of a textarea and choose the number of rows?

Tags: html, css

I have a text area and I want it to have 5 rows and the user can not rezize it `<textarea>`

Comment: `max-height` / `min-height` in CSS prevent resizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose the number of rows in the html like this:

```
<textarea id="textarea" rows="5" > </textarea>
```

And to disable the resize in css like this:

```
#textarea{
    resize: none;
}
```